# Mouseenter and Mouseleave giving undesired results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Im having an absolute nightmare with a plugin im trying to integrate.

Im trying to make X elements on my page flip on hover, and then on mouseout revert back.

Im using the flip function, and it works fine if i hover over an element, wait a few seconds for the flip to finsih animating, and then move my cursor. If i hover quickly however, my flip happens but messes up completely, and you cant quickly move your mouse across multiple elements.

I've tried using `stop()` to no avail so thought I'd ask on here, I've attached a fiddle, when looking at my fiddle, quickly run your mouse across all elements and you will see what I mean

http://jsfiddle.net/5JyVC/

```
$('.sec-con').prepend('<div class="target" style="width:100%; height:100%; z-index:999999; cursor:pointer;top:0; left:0; display:block; position:absolute; "></div>');
$('body').on({
    mouseenter: 
    function () {
        $(this).stop(true, true).next('.sector').flip({
            direction:'rl',
            color:'#2d6995',
            speed: 200,
            content:'<span class="all-vacancies">View all Vacancies <br />in this sector.</span><span class="read-more">Click here to read more.</span>'
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).next('.sector').revertFlip();
    }
}, '.target');
```

Comment: <s>Looks fine to me .. all elements flip as I mouse over them.</s> I see, they don't revert back.

Comment: Try hovering over just 1 element @FritsvanCampen, wait for it to flip, and then move your cursor off

Comment: It is not the flipping which does not work, but the reverting... I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have a rdy to go script but it does not use plugins... i wrote it. i have written it for webkit browsers .. youjust have to add -moz,-ms or whatever prefixes to the css .. you intrested to see that?

Comment: Id love to please @cocco

Comment: ok finished the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's something to do with the `flipLock` data attribute. If you mouseout too soon `flipLock` is `true` and the revert flip wont happen causing the next mouseover to start with the wrong content. So from then on you're flipping back and forth between the same content.

If you remove the flipLock detection and `return false` and add `stop` to the `animation` call in `flip` it will revert properly.

The animation looks a bit wonky though, I'm not sure what can be done about that.

This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5JyVC/5/ If you move fast enough it will still mess up, not sure why that is, maybe multiple mouseover events? This is what the original `flipLock` intended to prevent I guess.

Maybe `flipLock` should be more complex, when flipped, only allow flip backs and vice versa. The current implemenation of `flip` and `revertFlip` doesn't allow for this though.

Comment: It still breaks for me when I move the mouse really fast over all the flippers

Comment: Yea, I added some more.

Comment: I think the problem is with that flip plugin, it should not allow flipping twice, and it should remember when the unflip was called and trigger it at a later time if it is in the middle of a flip.

Comment: You could do that yea, but you don't want to keep scheduling flips like that, only the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way in pure css (as requested)

the javascript is here just to add the elements faster

Anyway i modified the function sothat you can add `HTMLElement`s direct to the function that adds the various divs that needs to be flipped.

A & B, where A is the front and B is the back.

in this example i add 6 elements to the page.

here is the javascript to test the elements

```
var D,
flip=function(A,B){// HTMLElement,HTMLElement - no text
 var box=D.createElement('div');
 box.appendChild(D.createElement('div')).appendChild(A);
 box.appendChild(D.createElement('div')).appendChild(B);
 return box;
},
init=function(){
 D=window.document;
 for(var i=0,f=D.createDocumentFragment();i<6;i++){
  var a=D.createTextNode('Front '+i),
  b=D.createTextNode('Back '+i);
  f.appendChild(flip(a,b));
 }
 D.getElementsByClassName('flip')[0].appendChild(f);
}
window.onload=init;
```

As you can see no eventlisteners or complex code as if you use css3 you totally can put the `:hover` on the divs without the need of javascript (mouseenter,mouseleave).

to add this animation to every element i added a class for the container of the elements.

```
html,body{width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;} /* important */
.flip{
 width:100%;height:100%; /* in this case the perspective center */
 -webkit-perspective:1200; /* is in the page center */
}
.flip>div{
 width:200px;height:160px; /* width && height of the flip box */
 float:left; 
 margin:16px;
 -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transition:all 600ms ease;/* animation speed is 600ms */
}
.flip>div>div{
 width:100%;height:100%; /*to fit the flip container*/
 -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;/* hide the back side */
 line-height:160px;text-align:center;/*center the text*/ 
 background-color:grey;/* both sides color */
}
.flip>div>:nth-child(2){
 -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 margin-top:-160px;/* hack so no need for position absolute*/
}
.flip>div:hover{
 /*-webkit-transition:all 1000ms ease 1000ms; 
  want to close it slowly with a delay? */
 -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
/* no position relative or absolute which slows down ios */
```

this is writtenfor webkit browsers (chrom, safari, android, ios)
i made it for my ipad.

to use it with firefox and the latest ie's that support css3 you need to duplicate this -webkit styles with the -moz,-ms,-o prefixes and check the support.

this example is based on 3d so the container has also a perspective value.
and the elements flip in real 3d and so you trigger the HW GPU acceleration on the various browsers.

the html just needs that container with the class `flip`

using classallows you to add multiple containers with multiple flipping elements.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>flip</title>
//add here the links to css3 or the <style>
//add here the the script or link to the script  
</head>
<body><div class="flip"></div></body>
</html>
```

so this is very simple as you can see but from this base you can create veri impressive animations just changind the flip css.

if you need some more advanced features you can handler that with javascript event

```
transitionend
```

if you want to add the boxes manually this is all you need to write.

```
<div class="flip">
 <div>
  <div>Element1 Front</div>
  <div>Element1 Back</div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <div>Element2 Front</div>
  <div>Element2 Back</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Want to triggerthe animation on **click/mouseevent/dragevent/scrollevent** whatever?

replace `.flip>div:hover` with `.flip>div.flipped`

and in javascript on event

```
this.parentNode.classList.toggle('flipped')
```

or

```
this.parentNode.classList.add('flipped') & this.classList.remove('flipped')
```

Now this is all about modern browsers and uses modern javascript&&css3 but as you want to flip something you anyway need a modern browser.
also *jQuery can't flip something in ie6*

like always

1. javascript handle the events or adds multiple elements
2. css to create the style of the page
3. html just for a basic structure.

for any other questions just ask

fiddle (test with chrome)

http://jsfiddle.net/gNB3z/2/